# Fireball damage within a forcecage

Tags: pathfinder-1e

There is nothing that prevent casting a *delayed blast fireball* and next a *forcecage*, right?

If yes, what would be an adequate damage "increment" of a fireball exploding entirely into the cage?

Comment: In some games, this is referred to as the "Chunky Salsa effect", although it usually applies to grenades instead of magical explosions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## The [*Fireball*](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/fireball.html) Inflicts Normal Damage

Although its burst is constrained by [*forcecage*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/forcecage.html#forcecage), the *fireball* inflicts normal damage. The enclosed space doesn't matter. The *fireball*'s burst has merely encountered an [obstacle](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37244/8610).

### It Wasn't Always This Way...

In the *Player's Handbook* (1978) for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* the spell *fireball* has a burst that

> does not expend a considerable amount of pressure, and the burst will generally conform to the shape of the area in which it occurs, thus covering an area equal to its normal spherical volume [The area which covered by the fireball is a total volume of roughly 33,000 cubic feet (or yards)]. (73)

Many DMs interpreted this to mean the area of a *fireball* could *fold in upon itself* in a small enough area, dealing damage multiple times to foes in tiny rooms, making *fireball* a *much* deadlier spell both for monsters and careless magic-users. Similar language exists in the *Player's Handbook* (1989) for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition*. This language is absent in *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* (2000) and many of its iterations, including *Pathfinder*.

### ...But It Can Be That Way Again

If homebrew is acceptable in the campaign--and nostalgia permeates the gaming group--there's Frank and K's prestige class **seeker of the lost wizard traditions** (available [here](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Seeker_of_the_Lost_Wizard_Traditions_(3.5e_Prestige_Class)) and [here](http://www.dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Seeker_of_the_Lost_Wizard_Traditions_(3.5e_Prestige_Class)) and [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-98384.html)). The class's 1st-level class feature spell reflection makes a *D&D 3.X* character's *lightning bolt* spells behave like *1E* and *2E* *lightning bolt* spells used to (i.e. bouncing off surfaces), yet it's not until the 3rd-level class feature burst conservancy (acquired, at the earliest, at character level 9) that a character's *fireball et al.* spells start folding back on themselves. Although sometimes considered a joke by critics, the class is playable and entertaining. Old-school gamers may enjoy the opportunity to play *3.X* (and, by extension, *Pathfinder*) casters with *1E* and *2E* flourishes.

Comment: +1 That and the bouncing lightning bolt were the terror of any party with a mage in those days...

Comment: I miss the bouncing lightning bolt....

Comment: This gave me some really nice ideas for a new Metamagic feat - Folding Spell.