# How Does the Grease Spell Interact with Fire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Can you light the spell grease on fire? If so, what are the effects of doing so? (How long does it burn, does it do damage to creatures standing in it / coated with it, etc.)

Comment: Although this question merits its own standalone answer, [this question is answered in answers to this *Pathfinder* question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46826/8610).

Comment: (With that in mind, maybe you should self-answer this question before somebody else swoops in?)

Comment: Related (3.5e): [How to tell when a material is flammable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48387/how-to-tell-when-a-material-is-flammable)

Comment: Related (Pathfinder):  [Can you light magically created grease on fire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46826/can-you-light-magically-created-grease-on-fire), [Would the grease spell with a flask of acid used as a power component work with burning spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87417/would-the-grease-spell-with-a-flask-of-acid-used-as-a-power-component-work-with)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### No, Grease (as per the spell), is not flammable.

There is already a spell that does this:

> Incendiary Slime
> (Complete Mage, p. 108)
> Level: Sorcerer 2, Wizard 2, 
> ...
> A slick, greasy liquid seeps from the targeted object, thoroughly coating it.
> **This spell functions like grease (PHB 237), but the liquid is also highly flammable.** If any fire damage is dealt within the area of the spell (or to the subject of the spell), the spell's area (or subject) bursts into flame. This effect deals 4d6 points of damage to anyone in the area (or holding the subject), but also ends the spell's duration. A successful Reflex save halves this damage. (emphasis mine)

They would not have created a level two spell that specifically calls out being flammable as the distinction if the level one spell were already flammable.

Answer (score 1):

### Grease puts out fires, and can be used to coat objects to prevent fire damage.

Since the grease has been conjured (is not an illusion) logic dictates it must have consistent material properties.

If the popular notion is that the grease is not flammable, then that (it’s fireproofness) is a useful property which can be utilized.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes here at all. This is a great and insightful answer. Thank you.